# Saving high-quality graphics through commands

Tags: graphics, export, image-processing, png-format

Say I make and display a graph in a Mathematica notebook:

```
graph = CompleteGraph[100]
```

If I drag the corner of the graph to increase its size, and then save it to a file, I get a really big detailed picture of the graph. This is great! I would like to do this without the dragging interaction. Specifically, I want to generate *really* big graphs and save very detailed images of them by script.

I tried using ImageResize on the graph:

```
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", ImageResize[graph]];
```

But it seems that the graph object is converted to an image (graphics object) which is scaled up and then saved - so the level of precision in the resulting image is no greater than if one were to call:

```
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", graph];
```

and manually scale up the image outside Mathematica.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Control image size as `Graph` option:

```
g = CompleteGraph[100, ImageSize -> 2000];
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", g]
```

Also if you already have graphics produced, you can use `Show` to programmatically resize it:

```
g = CompleteGraph[100, GraphStyle -> "LargeNetwork"];
gmag = Show[g, ImageSize -> 2000];
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", gmag]
```

In *Mathematica* there is a difference between `Graphics` objects and images:

```
RandomImage[1, {100, 100}]
```

[image]

```
In[1]:= % // Head
Out[1]= Image

Graphics[Raster[RandomReal[1, {100, 100}]]]
```

[image]

```
In[2]:= % // Head
Out[2]= Graphics
```

`ImageResize` is used for images and may result in the loss of resolution. Changing shown size of `Graphics` with `Show` will not result in loss of resolution.

Answer (score 6):

What I found to be working best is using before the final export.
Especially when your adding labels etc you get some problems (at least I do).

Example:

```
graph = CompleteGraph[100, VertexLabels -> "Name",ImageSize -> Scaled[10]];
Export["graaf.pdf", graph];
```

when I open the graaf.pdf at 100% and use the snipping tool I get:

[image]

Using:

```
graph2 = CompleteGraph[100, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

Now I have to enlarge the pdf to approx 4000% and I get again with the Snipping tool on the same vertex 80:

[image]

With the ImageSize at a certain level like mentioned and then exporting to a PNG file will also work but it takes more to get to the right resolution.

Answer (score 5):

*Usually*, another way to control the exported image size *would be*:

```
Export["graph.png", graph, ImageSize -> 2000]
```

This doesn't work correctly unless you prepare the graph with a sufficiently thin `EdgeStyle`. I did that in the example graph that I initially played with, because it looked better in the notebook to begin with.

Here is what I get in the external file from the above export command applied to a graph defined as

```
graph = CompleteGraph[100, EdgeStyle -> Thickness[.0001], ImageSize -> 360]
```

[image: ImageSize 2000]

and here is what I get when I double the width, `ImageSize -> 4000`:

[image: ImageSize 4000]

There is still something buggy to see here, though: the Thickness of the circles is scaled up, in the same way that the edge thickness becomes too thick if I don't set it to a small value beforehand.

**End edit**

In fact, I wonder if it would be better for you to export in vector format and not in a rasterized bitmap format. For example, if you can work with `PDF` files, you get much smaller file sizes with lots of detail. With this graph

```
graph = CompleteGraph[100, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thin,Opacity[.2]], ImageSize -> 360]
```

and the export command

```
Export["graph.pdf", graph]
```

you get a 77kB `PDF` file, whereas the exported `PNG` file above is almost 7MB large. Note that I didn't include an image size in the last command because it is irrelevant for the amount of detail in the exported vector format.

If you want to publish the exported figure on the web, it may also be useful to export as `SVG` because most browser now support it. Try this:

```
Export["graph.svg", graph]
```

and drag it to Firefox to see the amount of detail in this file.

Comment: Your 1st line of code did not work for me. Somehow `Export` did not respect `ImageSize` option to produce 2000px image. Did it work for you? My sistem is win7 M.8.0.4.

Comment: @Vitaly Sure, it works for me on Mac OS X, and it has always worked as far as I know. Maybe you should file a bug report...

Comment: It works for other types of graphics on my machine, but for Graph it produces an image where edges cannot be resolved - just uniform color disk. This is why I did not mention this variant in my solution. Format matters - .pdf works. I wonder what other people see on their systems.

Comment: @Vitaliy Ah, I just looked back at this and did indeed find that something doesn't work right. With the original graph, my first line indeed gives a `PNG` where the edges are so thick that they fill the area. I hadn't noticed that because I was using `EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thin,Opacity[.2]]` (which I added to make it look nicer in the notebook). So you're right.

Answer (score 5):

Just do the following, you are looking for `ImageResolution`

```
g = CompleteGraph[100];
exportDPI = 2000;

Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", g, ImageResolution -> exportDPI];
```

Comment: To me this seems to be the simplest solution and should be the accepted answer.