# Is there a way to increase the visual quality of mathematica picture

Tags: graphics

When exporting to a png or an eps file, the quality of Mathematica pictures is weak comparing say to pstricks --- which save only in ps or eps. For instance, the labels, but not only, seem a little bit fuzzy. Is there a way to enhance the rendering of the graphics.

When looking at the former questions of the same types like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43378/generating-high-quality-charts-in-mathematica-for-use-in-latex-and-word)

I find the Simon Wood's answer strange since it is only for Word and rasterization is not an enhanced way for postscript devices.

Comment: Give us please the examples of good and bad images?

Comment: Ok I will do it in the next few hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use higher image resolution:

```
Export["image.png", image, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two properties that you could look at to increase quality of the exported images are

`ImageSize`
and
`CompressionLevel`

**Example**

```
Export[file, extension, ImageSize -> 1200, "CompressionLevel" -> 0]
```